# Determine where converges pointwise

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I have doubts with this exercise

Decide where the series of functions $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\displaystyle\frac{7^n+3t^n}{3+7^nt^n}}, t\in[0,\infty]$ converges pointwise

My attemp:

If $t=0$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{}\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{7^n}{3} = 0} $ converges

If $t>0$ I don't know what happens

Comment: Please consider editing your question. It is hard to understand.

Comment: If $t=0$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{}\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{7^n}{3} } $ does not converge, so the sum does not converge

Comment: You could consider $t <-1, t=-1,-1<t<0, t=0, 0 < t <1, t=1,1<t$

Comment: I forget says that $t\in[0,\infty]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n : t \in \mathbb{R}_+ \mapsto \dfrac{7^n+3t^n}{3+7^n t^n}$.

If $t = 0$ then $f_n(0) = \dfrac{7^n}{3} \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$ therefore $\displaystyle \sum f_n(0)  $ is diverging.

If $0<t<7$ then $f_n(t) \underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\dfrac{7^n+3t^n}{7^nt^n}=\dfrac{1+3(t/7)^n}{t^n} \sim \dfrac{1}{t^n}$ so $\sum f_n(t)$ converges iff $\sum (1/t)^n$ converges so (as a geometric series) iff $|1/t|<1$ iff $t>1$.

Therefore for $0<t\leq1$, $\sum f_n(t)$ is divergent. And for $1<t<7$ we have $\sum f_n(t)$ convergent.

If $t = 7$ then $f_n(t) \sim \dfrac{4}{7^n}  $ and $\sum \dfrac{4}{7^n}$ is convergent so by comparison $\sum f_n(t)$ is convergent.

If $t>7$ then $f_n(t) \sim \dfrac{3t^n}{7^nt^n} = \dfrac{3}{7^n}$ and $\sum \dfrac{3}{7^n}$ is convergent thus by comparison $\sum f_n(t)$ is convergent.

To conclude, $\sum f_n$ converges pointwise on $(1,+\infty)$